# icacls, Network Service, and setting ACLs on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, access-control-list

Setting ACLs on Windows Server 2008 via the command line is giving me some problems. As per http://web2.minasi.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=26907 I've tried all sorts of variations:

C:\Windows\system32>icacls "D:\Websites\site.com\Web\bin*" /grant 'NT A
uthority\NETWORK SERVICE: (OI) (CI)M'

C:\Windows\system32>icacls "D:\Websites\site.com\Web\bin*" /grant "NETWORK SERVICE": (OI) (CI)M

And all variations in between. However, each try leads to i.e. "Invalid parameter "'NETWORK'"" depending on the variation above.

As per http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28WS.10%29.aspx (see in comments), it appears that others have experienced the same issue where the same command works on Windows 7/Vista/etc., but not on Windows Server 2008.

What's the best way to apply permissions to Network Service account on a directory and/or files via the command line in Windows Server 2008? Especially as there's no way to do multiple file permissions at once via the GUI (see [Windows Server 2008 - change security settings for multiple files at once](https://serverfault.com/questions/30991/windows-server-2008-change-security-settings-for-multiple-files-at-once)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line worked for me:

```
icacls testdir /grant "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService":(OI)(M)
```

and

```
icacls testdir /grant "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService":(CI)(M)
```

**Update:**
And this too:

```
icacls testdir /grant "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService":(OI)(CI)(M)
```

Comment: Igal: thx for the quick response. Turns out NetworkService (vs. Network Service - just like cacls) does the trick. However, although "Successfully processed" there's no change to the directory/file ACLs?!? Am I missing something obvious here? Did with another user and still no dice.

Comment: Of course, I'm running in an elevated cmd prompt.

Comment: Will mark your answer as correct and make a new question regarding how the cmd "successfully processes", but doesn't in fact make any changes.

Comment: This didn't work on Win Server 2008 for me.  I had to add space in "NetworkService" like "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE".

Answer (score 3):

You need to add OI and CI to effect the change to folder permission settings.

Example setting **Modify** permission to test folder for **Network Service** account:

```
icacls C:\Test /grant "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService":(OI)(CI)(M)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sid for network service like so:

```
icacls testdir /grant *S-1-5-20:(OI)(M)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to install a private certificate and grant full access to Network User. Here is the script that worked for me.

```
$certPath = 'C:\Certs\pwd-aks-client_cert.pfx'
$plainPwd = 'MyPwrd1!'
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $plainPwd -AsPlainText -Force 


#Install certificate to local machine
$cer = Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certPath -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My\ -Password $pwd

#Get the private key of the uploaded certificate
$rsaCert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions]::GetRSAPrivateKey($cer)

$fileName = $rsaCert.key.UniqueName
$path = "$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys\$fileName"

#Grant Full Access permission to Network service user
icacls $path /grant 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE:F'
```